# C# Datagridview set column width to prefered size when datagrid is on fill

Tags: c#, datagridview, width

I have a datagridview, that is set to "Fill" because that way you have no ugly blank spots. Now I want to resize 2 columns so the content is fully shown.

With this piece of code I can change the width of one column:

```
DataGrid.Columns[1].Width = DataGrid.Columns[1].GetPreferredWidth(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells, true);
```

But when I add it for the other cell that needs to be resized

```
DataGrid.Columns[5].Width = DataGrid.Columns[5].GetPreferredWidth(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells, true);
```

It overrides the first one, so only the last cell will be resized correctly.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Perform this in the parent's (Form's) Load event and not the constructor.

Even if the column's auto size mode is set to Fill, the columns' resulting values won't be set until it loads.

Let me know if I should elaborate. :)

Comment: I understand what you mean, I'll test this out this evening since I'm at work right now. I'll let you know the result! Thank you for answering after 1.5 year ;)

Comment: I found your question before I figured it out, and it was the only one I found. Came back to share the discovery. Hopefully that answers your question.